# ckeditor Mathml plugin installation

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin, ckeditor, mathml

I have been struggling to add mathml support for ckeditor . I have gone through few links but none seems to be working. I have even tried WIRIS plugin for ckeditor but it didn't gave me any result. For WIRIS i have followed [this](http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/ckeditor) link. Can someone please tell me how do I Implement mathml for ckeditor.?

**CKeditor Version:** 4.4.5

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have ckeditor in place all you have to do is the following:

1. [Download the WIRIS ckeditor plugin](http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/docs/ckeditor) and put the entire folder in the plugins folder of ckeditor:
   `/path-to/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris`
2. Add the script tag in the head right under the ckeditor tag.
3. Add this to the config property of ckeditor:

   ```
   extraPlugins:'ckeditor_wiris'
   allowedContent: true
   ```

Obviously you have to replace 'path-to' with your own path to where ckeditor is located.
It should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="path-to/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script src="path-to/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/plugin.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                    extraPlugins:'ckeditor_wiris',
                    allowedContent: true
                });

            </script>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to implement.

Comment: But CKeditor 5 doesn't have any plugins folder, what to do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please tell me how do I Implement mathml for ckeditor?

Why not let the MathML implementation for the web browser (Firefox supports MathML and WebKit also does, Google just have to enable it in Chrome).

If by "implement" you mean avoid CKEditor remove it when you try to include it
I had this problem when I wrote http://ckeditor.com/addon/texzilla. The source code of the plugin can be found at https://github.com/r-gaia-cs/CKEditor-TeXZilla (hope this help you find how to solve your problem).